# Safe way to make behavioral CSS trigger based on Javascript availability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been using this chunk of code to programmatically check if Javascript is available and use different behavioral CSS.

If Javascript is disabled, it will only show a normal unordered list.

If javascript is enabled, the list will be transformed after page load and **then** 
displayed to the user (avoiding the possible redraw/flicker of the unordered list element before/during transformation).

Is it possible that **document.getElementsByTagName('body')** can actually return an empty array at this stage of the page rendering, or is it always available?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .javascript ul { display:none; }
  .no_javascript ul { display:block; }
  .transformed { background-color: yellow; }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body class="no_javascript">

<script type="text/javascript">
// Inform us that javascript is available
(function() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    if ( body && body[0] ) {
        body[0].className = body[0].className.replace(/no_javascript/, "javascript");
    }
})();
</script>

 <ul>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
 </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".javascript ul").addClass("transformed").css('display','block');
});

</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Update: [How to eliminate post-render "flicker"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463670/how-to-eliminate-post-render-flicker) seems like a duplicate of my question. It was the problem I was trying to solve properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in HTML **scripts are parsed sequentially** (unless they have defer attribute, but that's another story).

If you look at [SCRIPT section in HTML4.01 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#h-18.1), you can see that:

> Scripts may be evaluated as a document loads to modify the contents of the document dynamically.

and that:

> All SCRIPT elements are evaluated in order as the document is loaded.

There's also an example of how the following script would affect resulting markup:

```
 <TITLE>Test Document</TITLE>
 <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
     document.write("<p><b>Hello World!<\/b>")
 </SCRIPT>
```

Has the same effect as this HTML markup:

```
 <TITLE>Test Document</TITLE>
 <P><B>Hello World!</B></P>
```

Since your script is contained right after BODY and has no DEFER attribute, it's probably safe to assume that during script execution, **BODY tag is already parsed and BODY element is already created** (but not the rest of the tree, such as elements created from the markup following script in question!).

And, of course, you should really **use faster, more compatible and shorter `document.body`** rather than `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` :)

In fact, I would replace this whole chunk:

```
(function() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    if ( body && body[0] ) {
        body[0].className = body[0].className.replace(/no_javascript/, "javascript");
    }
})();
```

with something like:

```
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('no_javascript', 'javascript');
```

Comment: I already replaced my getElementsByTagName('body')[0] with document.body in my code. Thanks for the suggestion. But shouldn't the code be document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('no_javascript', 'javascript') because strings are immutable in JavaScript? AFAIK, str.replace() returns the changed string, it doesn't do in-place manipulation of the string.

Comment: @Robin Thanks for catching that! I changed the answer to fix this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Well... you can use [document.body](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.body). It's rather safe.

Comment: in my experience, it always has been :)